# GUI.Label doesn't work in for loop

Tags: unity-game-engine, label, 2d, unity3d-gui

i have a problem with printing GUI elements in for loop pf OnGUI() method. In code listed below i create GUI.Label of user clicked on GUI.Box:

```
public List<string> messages = new List<string>();     
int dialogueMsg = 0;
     void OnGUI()
         {
             Event currentEvent = Event.current;
             if (enabled)
             {
                 GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 4 + Screen.height / 2, Screen.width - Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4));
                 GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width - Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4), "");
                 if (currentEvent.button == 0 && currentEvent.type == EventType.mouseDown)
                 {
                     for (int i = 0; i < messages.Count; i ++)
                     {
                         if (dialogueMsg < messages.Count)
                         {
                             print(dialogueMsg);
                             print(messages[dialogueMsg]);
                             GUI.Label(new Rect(25, 25, Screen.width - Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4), messages[dialogueMsg]);
                             ++dialogueMsg;
                             break;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             enabled = !enabled;
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 GUI.EndGroup();
             }
         }
```

And when user clicked - nothing happend, except printing correct values **dialogueMsg** and **messages[dialogueMsg]**. What am i doing wrong? Did anybody is familiar with this problem?

Comment: When your if statement, inside the for loop, are you wanting it to break out of the for loop the first time it is run? in both the if and else statement you have the break keyword which will break you out of the for loop regardless of if the count (i < messages.Count()) is exceeded.

Comment: Oh, i get it. I had just to set new String variable, that stores  messages[dialogueMsg] value and stand GUI.Label outside for-loop. 
Thx for the answer!

Comment: @CalebB Might want to post it as an answer so the OP can accept it

Answer (score 0):

In both the `if` and `else` statements you have the **break** keyword, thus the `for` loop will only run once then break out of the loop, regardless of if `i < messages.Count()` or not. Just take out the break keyword from the `if` or `else`, or both, code block(s) where you want the loop to continue then you should be all set for that part.

Comment: I've already do it, and nothing changes. And there is very odd problem: I separate OnGUI method, make new MyMethod() that holds GUI.Label call in it... and it works! I post my code, when i will be at home

Comment: What is your desired action from this method? I see that it should create and populate GUI Labels with your messages but is there something else that's suppose to take place in addition to this? Can you add more surrounding code possibly?